# Segundo Like não funciona SQLIte

Tags: android, sqlite, operador-like

Bom, ao fazer uma query:

```
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT nome, imagem, descricao FROM Marcas WHERE descricao LIKE ? OR nome LIKE ?", new String[]{name});
```

Somente retorna resultados através da descrição, ou seja, o segundo like não é testado, ou não funciona. Não dá nenhum erro, só não retorna nada. Se eu tiro o segundo like funciona tanto por nome quanto por descricao. Mas o que preciso é pesquisar via nome e descrição.

Como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Entaum @genSkywalker que eu saiba, o "OR" funciona sim com "LIKE" no sqlite.

Você precisa montar sua query usando `colunatbX LIKE '%string%' OR colunatbZ LIKE '%string%'` ou algo do tipo.
Dai @Marcelowq, para resolver da melhor forma, tente fazer algo assin ó:

```
String ds = "'%"+tuaVarDesc+"%'";
String nm = "'%"+tuaVarNome+"%'";
String cmd = "SELECT nome, imagem, descricao FROM Marcas WHERE descricao LIKE "+ds+" OR nome LIKE "+nm;
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(cmd, null);
```

Lenbrando que na clausula **LIKE** do sql, o caracter "%" seguido de outro qualquer caracter não-extendido, representa uma sequencia de caracteres na consulta, ou seja, um curinga, assim, se voce usar '%string%', vai retornar qualquer coisa que contenha a palavra **string** em qualquer posição do texto.

como voce postou pouco código, ficamos sem saber o que vc já tem ai, mas isso resolveria pra voce.

com like eu testei aqui no sqlite e retornou o que eu quiz, em ambas as posições do meu **LIKE**.

Comment: Mas o que quero é passar uma string e pesquisar tanto em `nome` quanto em `descricao`. Essa string é um parâmetro de quando chama o método na pesquisa.

Comment: mas com isso o parametro passado para "rawquery(...)" faz exatamente isso, ou seja, pesquisa  pela palavra "string" em qualquer posição no campo descricao **OU** no campo nome.

Comment: Então, isso que eu tô dizendo. Quero fazer isso mas não tá dando certo. Mas a query tá certa, Executo ela no sqlite expert e funciona. Só no android que não.

Comment: pode postar mais codigo pra eu poder ter uma ideia mais clara?

Answer (score 1):

Faltou mais um item "name" no array do segundo parâmetro do método rawQuery. Deveria ficar assim: new String[]{name, name}. Para cada "?" na string SQL do primeiro parâmetro, o método tenta pegar um item no array citado para substituir o "?” correspondente. Como você usa 2 "?", precisa de um Array com 2 items.